# How to Center a TextView?

Tags: android

I want to know how to center a TextView without using any of the class files.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="APW" />
```

Comment: class files? use `android:gravity="center"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set:

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Edit: Sorry did not see that Sherif elKhatib suggested the same

Answer (score 0):

If if you want to center the text in relation to the text view:

```
android:gravity="center"
```

if you want to center the textview in relation to the parent layout:

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers but I already have it from the first answer sorry